# Find all $f:\mathbb{Z} ^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$, such that $\forall p(x) \in P[\mathbb{Z}]: \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: f(p(a),p(b)) = p(f(a,b))$

Tags: functions, contest-math, alternative-proof, solution-verification

> Find all $f:\mathbb{Z} ^2 \to \mathbb{Z}$, such that $\forall p(x) \in P[\mathbb{Z}]: \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: f(p(a),p(b)) = p(f(a,b))$

This question was given in a contest-math context, where we had 20 minutes two solve 3 (easy, first stage) problems in teams of 4. **Here is my solution** (I hope it's correct):

Consider $p(x)=a$, then:

$f(p(a),p(b))= p(f(a,b)) \to $

$$\to \forall a\in \mathbb{Z}:f(a,a)=a$$

Consider $p(x)=x-b$, then:

$f(p(a),p(b))= p(f(a,b))\to f(a-b,0)=f(a,b)-b \to $

$$\to \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: f(a,b)=b + f(a-b,0)$$

So now we will try to find $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z} : f(y,0) = ?$

Consider $p(x) = x^2 - y x$:

and we will choose (y,0):
$f(p(y),p(0))= p(f(y,0))\to f(0,0)=f(y,0)\cdot f(y,0)-y \cdot f(y,0) \to f(y,0)\cdot (f(y,0)-y) =0\to$

$$\to\forall y\in \mathbb{Z}: f(y,0)=0 \lor f(y,0)=y$$

**let's assume by contradiction** that there are $a \ne0,b\ne 0$ that $f(a,0)=a$ and $f(b,0)=0$

(I did not include 0 because $f(0,0)=0$)

Consider $p(x)=bx$, then:

$f(p(a),p(0))= p(f(a,0))\to f(ba,0)=bf(a,0) \to f(ba,0)=ba$

Consider $p(x) = ax$, then:

$f(p(b),p(0))= p(f(b,0))\to f(ba,0)=af(b,0) \to f(ba,0)=0$

Therefore $0=f(ba,0)=ba \to ba=0  \to $ contradiction ($a\ne 0, b\ne 0$)

so for every function $f$ that fits the criteria of the question, either $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}: f(y,0) = 0$ or (EXCULISIVE) $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}: f(y,0)=y$

Let's split it into 2 case:

**1.** $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}: f(y,0)=y$. Then, $f(a,b) = f(a-b,0)+b \to f(a,b) = a$

Let's see if all of those functions fit the criteria of the question:

$\forall p(x) \in P[\mathbb{Z}]: \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: f(p(a),p(b)) = p(f(a,b)) \iff p(a)=p(a) \iff True$

**2.** $\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}: f(y,0)=0$. Then, $f(a,b) = f(a-b,0)+b \to f(a,b) = b$

Let's see if all of those functions fit the criteria of the question:

$\forall p(x) \in P[\mathbb{Z}]: \forall a,b \in \mathbb{Z}: f(p(a),p(b)) = p(f(a,b)) \iff p(b)=p(b) \iff True$

So we found that the only 2 functions that fit the criteria are $f(a,b)=a$ and $f(a,b)=b$

Given the context of the question, I am sure that there must be a simpler solution. Can you think of any?

P.S: I would love to give credit to the creator of the question, but I don't know who he is.

Comment: For $p(x)=0$ one gets that $f(0,0)=0$. For $p(x)=(x-a)(x-b)$ one gets $0=f(0,0)=(f(a,b)-a)(f(a,b)-b)$. So, $f(a,a)=a$. If $a\neq b$ and $f(a,b)=a$, then for and arbitrary pair $c,d$ we take $p(x)=\frac{d-c}{b-a}(x-a)+c$ we get $f(c,d)=f(p(a),p(b))=p(f(a,b))=p(a)=c$. Similarly, if for some $a\neq b$ one has $f(a,b)=b$, then for an arbitrary pair $c,d$ one uses the same polynomial as before, but at the end one would get $f(c,d)=p(b)=d$.

Comment: @egorovik The only problem with your proof is that you can't always take $p(x) = \frac{d-c}{b-a} (x-a) +c$ because it doesn't always have integer coefficients ($b-a$ does not alway divide $d-c$.)

Comment: Oh, I see. That's what that symbol means. Let me re-look at it.

Comment: Well, kind of hard to think of another way for that part (that the values are only one of the projections) after having seen yours, even more since that part is quite short with the polynomials $p(x)=ax$ and $p(x)=bx$. That part could just be done the same way. Well, at least some reduction for the rest, for the part of deducing that the values are projections to the coordinates.